# The Schwartz-space is not normed.

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I'm supposed to prove that the topology of the Schwartz-Space $\mathcal{S}:=\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not induced by a norm by assuming that there exists such a norm $||\cdot||$.

As a first step, I'm supposed to prove that for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a constant $C_N$ such that $|f|_N \leq C_N \cdot ||f||$ for every $f \in \mathcal{S}$, where

$|f|_N = \sup \{ (1+|x|)^N \cdot |\partial^\alpha f(x)| ;  x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \alpha \in \mathbb{N}_0^n, |\alpha| \leq N \}$.

My Question is:

How do I prove the inequality involving $||f||$ without knowing what $||f||$ looks like? I only now that it meets the following condition (per assumption):

A sequence of Schwartz-functions $(f_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N} } \subset \mathcal{S}$ converges to f in the Schwarz-space (i.e. in $| \cdot |_N) \Longleftrightarrow ||f_k - f|| \longrightarrow 0$, as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Hint: as in proving that $C^\infty$ is not normed, show that higher derivatives cannot be estimated by lower-order derivatives. :)

Comment: paul garrett’s comment gives you the full idea – for your specific question, you know that any sequence converging for $\|\cdot\|$ must converge for $|\cdot|_N$. Deducing the inequality is then an easy consequence (for instance, by contradiction) that you should be able to find in any lecture notes about normed spaces (the equivalent definitions for equivalent norms).